# fatal error C1001: An internal error (compiler file 'msc1.cpp', line 1518) with vs2017 15.8.4

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, unreal-engine4

When I use VS2017 15.8.4 and Fastbuild 0.96 to do distributed build for Unreal Engine 4.2, I got the error below:

> 4>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\enterprise\vc\tools\msvc\14.15.26726\include\comdef.h : fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.
>   4>(compiler file 'msc1.cpp', line 1518)
>   4> To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near the locations listed above.
>   4>Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++
>   4> Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information

I found this issue was introduced by latest Visual Studio for distributed build, because:
1. I didn't get this issue in VS2017 15.7.6 which is an older version
2. There is no issue when disabling distributed build

I found the same issue in [visual studio forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/313306/vs2017-158-internal-compiler-error-msc1cpp-line-15-1.html), but looks like they didn't provide a solution for VS2017 15.8.4. Is there any solution for VS2017 15.8.4?

Comment: There's no question in your post. What are you expecting from us? The suggestion given in the linked document is to upgrade to 16.0 or you could downgrade to 15.7.6. Why is that not acceptable to you?

Comment: I've seen these in MS compilers since 1995. You didn't find anything shocking. MS got better, but occasionally you still write a code that stumps the compiler. I've seen GCC equivalent few times, but yeah -- not as often.

Comment: @C.M. But here its MS code that is stumping it's own compiler.

Comment: @john yep. you probably referred it in some unexpected context that compiler writers didn't foresee. Or maybe something somewhere overflows...

Comment: Distributed builds can play tricks with precompiled headers, etc -- this can tax compiler. I suggest trying to figure out the difference between translation unit (as observed by compiler) when it is build normally vs fastbuild build

Comment: Looking at the issue your referred to (Conflict between preprocessor and #import) I theorise that fastbuild plays tricks with header files (by combining them?) and you end up with some conflict between preprocessor and #import directive in one translation unit

Answer (score 1):

Just a record. After I added .AllowDistribution = false and .AllowCaching = fasle on the issue modules(which means disable distribution and cache on the issue modules), the issue addressed. Now I can build UE 4.2 both in VS2017 15.8.4 and VS2017 15.8.5 with FASTBuild. Thanks.